How to update Vue JS reactive binding while a component is hidden
I have a well-established Vue JS app, which is all working fine to the human eye, but during automated QA testing there's a subtle effect which fails the tests due to a 2ms period of having no data displayed. I've just upgraded the app from v2 to v3 of Vue and so I suspect this is a change in the ordering of the reactive flow.
I have a table of data, which is populated by an API call. During the API call I set a loading data variable which flips the table to a skeleton-loader component, thus hiding the table. The response data is committed to a local store, which is bound to the table rows via some computed methods (to do filtering). After the API response, and the wrapped store commit, is finished I clear the loading flag. This flips the table back into view and hides the skeleton loader.
This all works fine but I've found that the sequence of events isn't quite what I expected. The computed methods don't recalculate their values until after the loading flag is cleared. This means the table first displays with empty data, then 2ms later the computed data updates and populates the rows.
I my tests (using webdriverio, mocha etc) I await the table appearing, then assert the rows have the expected data. The problem is that the rows are queried during the 2ms window and the results are incorrect (0).
Initially I thought that it was a simple race condition with the DOM buffering so I added a nextTick which delayed the settnig of the loaded flag. This didn't fix it, so I added up to ten nested nextTick's and then I added a 2 second setTimeout delay... and the computed results always came 2ms after the delayed loading change.
I realised then, that due to the reactive dependency cleverness, while the table is hidden Vue thinks there's no point in calculating the updated row values - makes sense. So whatever I do, the row values computed methods won't get triggered until after the table is displayed (loading=false). So they will always lag by 2ms and I will always have this race-condition in my tests.
This is reproduced in this https://jsfiddle.net/ecjmstbq/4/
When you click [load], it pretends to use an API which stores its responses in a data variable which is bound to a computed filter. (mocking the API and Store)
You will see the sequence in the console:
"rows set"
"got response"
"done loading"
"rows filter updated"

The problem being that "done loading" happens before the "rows filter updated", i.e. the computer filter is not run until after the loading=false displays the table.
"rows set"       // this is the raw data being updated
"got response"   // the API callback returns
"done loading"   // loadig is false, the table is displayed 
"rows filter updated"    // but only now does the row-data get updated - TOO LATE!

If you remove the v-if, e.g. change <div v-if="loading"> to <div v-if="false">
you will see the sequence of events changes to :
"rows set"
"rows filter updated"
"got response"
"done loading"

which solves the problem, in that the values are updated first, as soon as the dependent data variable's value has changed. It does not wait until the loading variable sets.
"rows set"             // this is the raw data being updated
"rows filter updated". // the computed value gets immediately refreshed into the table
"got response"         // the API response resolves
"done loading"        // (not used) but this would be when I'd want the refreshed table to show

So my question is: can I force the bound data to trigger a computed update before showing the table?
Perhaps is there a trick where it's "invisible" but attached to the DOM.
Or is there a built-in way to do this in Vue?
Or is there some other way to rearrange the loading to avoid the 2ms blank table?

consider using <table v-show="!loading"> instead of <table v-else>

omg perfect. it resolves it. please answer and I'll accept it.

So I guess the difference is a v-if=false component simply doesn't exist so isn't bound. But a v-show=false component exists but is hidden, and will receive binding updates?

It's possible but not conventional to do this with v-show. What you currently have is regular Vue code, so the problem is primarily with tests, which the question doesn't contain. Generally you just do await mockedFetchPromise; await nextTick() in unit tests, and it can be asserted normally without fragile workarounds. In e2e tests it would be different but still controllable. Notice that since you have async side effect (fetch), waiting for nextTick alone is not enough. In some cases to wait for flushPromises utility to make it stable
